# Visual-Studio-2017 can not Debug Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I have a problem with my `VisualStudio 2017`. I can't debug my javascript code.
First there was that problem that my breakpoints will not be hit:
`the breakpoint will not currently be hit.`

Now I got another problem here is a screenshot of the Error Message:
[ErrorMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWH4t.png)

Currently I am Using `VS2017`, `asp.net`, `angular.js`, `IIS`, Chrome(also tried with IE Edge and Firefox).

Comment: Hi, please try to set Internet Explorer as the browser when debugging, you will need to make sure that "Disable script debugging" is checked in your IE Internet Options, Advanced tab.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you wnat to use Visual studio to Debug JS i think you `HAVE TO USE INTERNET EXPLORER`

Another way is to use `Visual studio Code` with integrated debugger `(https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/angular-tutorial)`

or (the way i use) use the `Chrome Developer Tools`

```
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that this will solve your problem, but I normally use Chrome Developer Tools for debugging javascript.

> https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/